# Flutter shrinkwrap breaks page height

Tags: flutter

`shrinkwrap: true` in `ListView.builder` makes `AnimatedPositioned` appear at the end of the widget (middle of the screen) instead of the bottom of the screen. Changing `shrinkwrap: false` causes an error because the `ListView` does not have size. 
Is there a way to give `ListView.builder` a height or make `AnimatedPositioned` appear at the bottom of the screen?

[image: Widget tree]

Comment: Can you please share the related code in order to understand whats happening inside there?

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the `ListView` widget into `SizedBox` to give it a height.

and if you want to make it size responsive for different screens you can use `MediaQuery`.